# If use 'function' to calculate 'parameter' will lead to logic resource occupation in Verilog HDL

Tags: verilog, fpga

I want to achieve some complicated calculation in parameter statement, but this will make my code hard to read. I know that some other FPGA engineers use 'function' to do that. The code is like what showed below:

```
function  integer calc_head_len;
input [11:0]  DFF;
begin
  calc_head_len=0;
  if(DFF[11])       calc_head_len=calc_head_len + 16;
  if(DFF[10])       calc_head_len=calc_head_len + SFL_WIDTH;
  if(DFF[9])        calc_head_len=calc_head_len + FDSTI_WIDTH_PORT;
  if(DFF[8])        calc_head_len=calc_head_len + FDSSI_WIDTH_PORT;
  if(DFF[7])        calc_head_len=calc_head_len + BN_WIDTH;
end
endfunction

localparam  FRAME_HEAD_LEN=calc_head_len(DFF);
```

The question is, firstly, as i know, 'parameter' assignment should only use constant expression, but 'function' could calculate variables, so why that is ok?

Secondly, 'parameter' will not occupy logic resources because they can be calculated during synthesis stage, but will 'function' be calculated in the same time? or it will occupy extra resources?

thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

If a function’s arguments are only constants or parameters, and return value of the function is solely dependent on those arguments, then the tool will propagate the return value as another constant. So it won’t take up any extra resources.